# How to pivot the column values dynamically in to rows and displaying the pivoted column names under each column value?

Tags: sql

Please help me on this.Here the category is dynamic and how many ever categories added in future must be shown in pivoted output.

I have a table like this.

```
Create table [Pivot_Check]
(    
[Id] Int Identity(1,1)
,[Category] Varchar(1) 
)

Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('A')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('B')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('A')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('B')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('C')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('D')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('C')
Insert into [Pivot_Check] Values('D')

Select * from [Pivot_Check]
```

Table data will be like this!

```
Id  Category
1   A
2   B
3   A
4   B
5   C
6   D
7   C
8   D
```

How do I get the output like this?

````````````````````````````
Id   A   B      C       D
```````````````````````````
1   A      NULL NULL    NULL
2   NULL   B    NULL    NULL
3   A      NULL NULL    NULL
4   NULL   B    NULL    NULL
5   NULL   NULL C       NULL
6   NULL   NULL NULL    D
7   NULL   NULL C       NULL
8   NULL   B    NULL    D
````````````````````````````

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as:

```
DECLARE @DynamicPivotQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @ColumnName AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

--Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column 
SELECT @ColumnName= ISNULL(@ColumnName + ',','') 
       + QUOTENAME(Category)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM [Pivot_Check]) AS [Pivot_Check]

--Prepare the PIVOT query using the dynamic 
SET @DynamicPivotQuery = 
  N'SELECT Id, ' + @ColumnName + '
    FROM [Pivot_Check]
    PIVOT(Min([Category]) 
          FOR [Category] IN (' + @ColumnName + ')) AS PVTTable'
--Execute the Dynamic Pivot Query
EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicPivotQuery
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://rextester.com/JHRL48547)</kbd>

Comment: replacing count([Category] with MIN([Category] will give exact output

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
SELECT id, 

CASE WHEN Category = 'A' THEN 'A' ELSE Null END AS A,
CASE WHEN Category = 'B' THEN 'B' ELSE Null END AS B,
CASE WHEN Category = 'C' THEN 'C' ELSE Null END AS C,
CASE WHEN Category = 'D' THEN 'D' ELSE Null END AS D

FROM Pivot_Check

ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: how many ever categories can be added in future .. the case statement will not work in that case..

Comment: Thanks Neil, This will work for Fixed categories, Any ways this will help me in another scenario. Thanks for the reply